# Could I use port 443 for my webservice or is this port reserved?

Tags: web-services, networking, server, backend, firewall

I have an app which uses a backend (REST webservice) on a public server. Currently I am using 8080 as the incoming port and asked myself if this is correct. In theory I could choose almost any port. Theoretically... But it is advisable to use a non-reserved port.

I once heard that calling a web service with an "exotic" port could be blocked in a public WLAN. Due to firewall/proxy rules. Could that really happen?

Would it make sense to use port 443 for the web service? (I use a SSL certificate on my backend)

Answer (score 0):

This concept is pretty difficult to tackle, there are a lot of options when considering networked services. I'd advise **against using a [well known port](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml)** for your web service in general, although in the case of `REST` there is a case to be made.

As you mentioned, obscure port numbers can be blocked inside certain networks by strict sys admins. Operating your service over `TLS` on `port 443` is a secure and reliable way to access your api from within a network.

Being that REST is an `http(s)` api, and being that port 443 is designated for `https` traffic, using 443 for `https-REST api` seems appropriate.

TLDR; It's okay to use the well known http(s) ports, 80 and 443, for your `REST` api